# Styling button with drawable background and drawable left

Tags: android, button, styling

I suspect I'm going to have to do this the hard way, but here goes

I have this:

```
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/favouritesButton"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5sp"
            android:text="@string/favourites"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/shopping_basket_90x75"
            android:enabled="false"
            style="@style/BtnBigGreenLeft" />
```

Which gives me this

[image: Styled button with drawable image and border]

What the client wants is this (different drawable image but you get the idea)

[image: Button stays button and image is there]

Is this possible, or do I have to break it out into separate elements to get it to work?

Comment: Is it a complete image or two different button?

Comment: The compound drawables will always be placed inside the textview view. If your background covers the complete background of the textview, you'll always end up with what you've currently got. You can integrate a margin in the background drawable though, but I would recommend using seperate layouts

Comment: It's one button. I have assets for the image and the button colours separately, which is why I used drawbableLeft but it insists on wrapping the drawable as well as the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea just break it down. It will solve you many future problems with any other solution.

And make the Linear layout the wraps it all clickable.

Comment: Thanks - I was thinking of subclassing Button but that got way too hard :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my english.

If you want that all the picture will be clickable you can fix it simply

but if you want that only the green area will be clickable it should be harder

Comment: Whole thing clickable is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my english again.

if you want whole thing clickable you only should to change the picture in the Paint program on your PC and change the correct pic to the new pic that you made and that it.

I hope it will halp you.

Comment: Good idea but that doesn't work - I would have to craft 9 patches and stuff for 20 odd buttons. I will split the formatting out.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you cant do this in one button.

Try to use the ImageButton on the image and break it down to 2 diference buttons(button and imagebutton) or just use the Paint program on your PC and put the image on the ImageButton background (the second I think easyer).